# Fantasy manga where MC can raise undead, and was abandoned by the hero party

Tags: story-identification, manga

The story is about a kid who has undead-raising skills and was abandoned by the hero party. He was then scouted by a demon lord succubus.....I think it was a succubus, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember any details of the appearance of the main character?

Comment: i already found the manga the guy below me had given the answer it is The Rise of the Imemployed Wise Man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*The Rise of the Unemployed Wise Man*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/TheRiseOfTheUnemployedWiseMan)

> When a young Farm Boy named Karna turns thirteen, he's officially recognized as an adult and undergoes the Revelation ceremony to receive a title from Heaven's Gods to determine his lot in life. To his surprise, he's given the title of "Wise Man" along with the "Necromancy" skill, granting him incredible magical power. Elated by this discovery, Karna immediately decides to put his new talents to work by becoming an adventurer to earn money for his ailing grandparents. Things couldn't get better when he's scouted to join the party of the Hero himself, which comes with a lucrative salary.
>
> But after his first month on the job, his gross yet powerful abilities get him kicked out of the party with no money to show for it. Forced to become a solo adventurer, Karna then stumbles upon the lair of the Demon Lord of Lust, Cecilia Israfilia. After watching him easily defeat one of her strongest generals, she offers him a job rather than retribution. And so the boy who should have been a hero to humanity turns against it for the sake of earning money for his family. The rising of the formerly unemployed Wise Man begins!

Found with a search for `manga necromancer succubus`

Comment: thank you my friend i have been trying to find it for 2 days now XD

Comment: Jesus these Anime titles are getting worse every day.

Comment: @gamerGypps: They're kind of hearkening back to Victorian titles: "Gerald Bates: A tale wherein a boy becomes a man and loses a fortune, and then gains the world" :-D